# Changing address page url

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I would like to change the address of a website , but I do not know. For example, " www.page.com/contact-us " and it will change to " www.page.com/kontakt " . How can I do this?
I just want to translate my address of the page that was understood in my country.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a CMS Page - you can change it in the `admin panel -> CMS -> Pages -> tab Page Information -> URL Key`. But Contact Us is a little bit different. It's not a CMS Page but a separate extension. So you can use `admin panel -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management` or to directly edit it in the core files (but this way it will be changed generally - for all websites/store views). The file is `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml` -> change the value in tag `<frontName>`.

Comment: I have 2 adress. New and old. I have 3 Path ID, Reference Path, Target Path. Where i should instert that adress. Idk what i should write under Path ID, i cant make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can do this only change by `frontName` of `Mage_Contacts` Module.

Create An Custom module which have only  have config.xml and redefine frontName

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_CustomModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Amit_CustomModule>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <contacts>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Mage_Contacts</module> <!-- route for module Mage_Contacts-->
            <frontName>kontakt</frontName> <!-- change frontname -->
          </args>
      </contacts>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page is cms page than and if your site has multi language than you need to create separate page for each store view and change the "url key" field in cms page and edit your country language wise.